# Can I have two separate API calls in one resolver file? (Angular 9)

Tags: angular

I have this route:

```
{
    path: ':c/:u/listview/:site',
    component: SiteslistComponent,
    resolve: {
        apiData: ApiResolver
    }
}
```

And I have this resolver file:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Resolve, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { ApiService } from './api.service';

@Injectable()
export class ApiResolver implements Resolve<any> {

    public _customer;
    public _userId;

    constructor(
        private apiService:ApiService,
        private route:ActivatedRoute
    ) {
        let hash = window.location.hash;
        let params = hash.split('/');
        this._customer = params[1]; 
        this._userId = params[2];// <<< USE THIS WHEN DEPLOYING TO PRODUCTION
    }

    resolve() {
        if (isNaN(this._userId)) {
            this._userId = 14152;
        }
        return this.apiService.getSites(this._customer, this._userId);
    }


}
```

I need to add a new route to my app that also uses a resolver.

```
{
    path: ':c/:u/siteoverview/:siteid/overview',
    component: SiteOverviewComponent,
    resolve: {
        apiData2: ApiResolver
    }
}
```

But I'm confused. Can I use the same resolver file and add a second resolve function somehow? Or do I need a whole separate resolver file for each resolve function I need to create?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `data` option in your route configuration to send something to the resolve function. Further this will be used to distinguish between api calls.

```
{
    path: ':c/:u/siteoverview/:siteid/overview',
    component: SiteOverviewComponent,
    resolve: {
        apiData2: ApiResolver
    },
    data: {
      resolveMethod: 'getSites'
    }
},
{
    path: ':c/:u/siteoverview/:siteid/overview',
    component: SiteOverviewComponent,
    resolve: {
        apiData2: ApiResolver
    },
    data: {
      resolveMethod: 'getUsers'
    }
}
```

**resolver.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class ApiResolver implements Resolve<any> {
  ...
  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {
    const method = route.data['resolveMethod'];
    return this[method]();
  }

  getSites() {
    if (isNaN(this._userId)) {
        this._userId = 14152;
    }
    return this.apiService.getSites(this._customer, this._userId);
  }

  getUsers() {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Ah ha!! That makes a whole lot of sense. Didn't realize there was that additional method capability via the `data:` object. Thanks!